# Memory Error while loading a large JSON file python 3.4

Tags: python, json, numpy

I'm trying to load a large Json file (size: 8,5 GB) using the following command `pandas.read_json(myfile)`

which throws a memory error

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-88d3fb70f2f4> in <module>()
----> 1 df1=pd.read_json("part1")

/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/json.py in read_json(path_or_buf, orient, typ, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates, keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float, date_unit, encoding, lines)
    279         obj = FrameParser(json, orient, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates,
    280                           keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float,
--> 281                           date_unit).parse()
    282 
    283     if typ == 'series' or obj is None:

/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/json.py in parse(self)
    347 
    348         else:
--> 349             self._parse_no_numpy()
    350 
    351         if self.obj is None:

/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/json.py in _parse_no_numpy(self)
    564         if orient == "columns":
    565             self.obj = DataFrame(
--> 566                 loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None)
    567         elif orient == "split":
    568             decoded = dict((str(k), v)

MemoryError:
```

I've got a phisical RAM of 32 GB, i'm working on a CentOs virtual machine in which I have 28 GB of RAM.
Is there a way to overcome this problem ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You would need 8.5 GB of memory to store the bytes read from the JSON file; you need *far* more to store a `dict` resulting from decoding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

break the json according to your available physical memory into files less than your ram, then load each and save it before loading another json file

Comment: do you have any idea how to break the json file ?

Comment: which os are you using>

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1588/break-a-large-file-into-smaller-pieces

go through this link

Comment: @Exprator Nice information but that leads not to a Python based solution.